# How to add list of Nodes in existing Node Xml in groovy

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

I have such a XML structure, with list of 'attachments', and I want iterate incoming `List<String> files` and create a groovy.util.Node for each of them and then return the builded Node. In code below I use only the fist element from list(base64 file), but I want to create `attachments` dynamically based on array size. I am new in groovy and can't find the way how to expand the Node properly.

```
import groovy.abi.XML

class TestService {
    
    Node buildNode(List<String> files) {
        Node node = XML.builder().
            "sab:sendExternalEmail"("xmlns:sab": "http://sab/") {
                "sab:to"('client@gmail.com')
                "sab:subject"('Reply')
                "sab:body"('Body')
                "sab:from"('sender@gmail.com')
                "sab:attachments"() {
                    "sab:attachment"() {
                        "sab:fileName"('file1')
                        "sab:fileBase64"(files[0])
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow. that's my ancient code )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to give you an idea how to work with builders:

```js
import groovy.util.NodeBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil


def attachments = [
    "name 1": "content 1",
    "name 2.txt": "content 2"
]

def xml = new NodeBuilder().a{
  for(a in attachments){
    attacchment{
      fileName(a.key)
      fileBase64(a.value)
    }
  }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>
  <attacchment>
    <fileName>name 1</fileName>
    <fileBase64>content 1</fileBase64>
  </attacchment>
  <attacchment>
    <fileName>name 2.txt</fileName>
    <fileBase64>content 2</fileBase64>
  </attacchment>
</a>
```